# UIButton and UIBarButtonItem are initialized at different time frames?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've wired a `UIButton` and a `UIBarButtonItem` in interface builder. When I invoke this method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

I've realized that the UIButton is not initialized (it is still nil), while the UIBarButtonItem is correctly initialized.

I'm wondering if they are initialized at different time frames, or is there any other reason?

Comment: There is another reason, but.. Will need some more intel. How are you using both objects?

Comment: I haven't used them yet in the code. The idea is to add the UIBUtton to the navigation bar (to handle multiple buttons in a bar in iOS4). The UIBarButtonItem is just a test.

Comment: You shouldnt add UIButtons to NavigationBars. You should always use UIBarButtonItems for that

Comment: In code you init a barbutton item on a navbar with the following code ---> [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:clearButton] <--- there should prolly be something similar with interface builder

Comment: @Totumus Maximus In iOS4 you can't add multiple UIBarButtonItems on the right (setRightBarButtonItems:animated:) is not supported. I've been told I need to add my custom view.

Comment: Check this blog post then, it is said to work for ios4.0: http://osmorphis.blogspot.nl/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

Comment: @Totumus Maximus Thanks for the link. I'm doing as the article suggest. But the buttons don't show up for some reason...

Comment: can you show me what exactly you have done?

Comment: It worked. Thanks, Do you want to add the answer for this ? So I can up vote ?

Comment: Here you go and your welcome^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is found at:
http://osmorphis.blogspot.nl/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

What is done there to make multiple buttons available for iOS 4.0 is to make a container (toolbar) for the multiple buttons, then put the toolbar on the navbar. This way multiple buttons are ezily added. (See also comments beneath question)